# html tbody dropdown appears above thead

Tags: php, html

For some reason my tbody appears above thead section. Can't figure out why

```html
<table id="myTable" class="table table-inverse table-hover">
    <thead id = "headings" class = "thead-default">
        <tr>
      <th>Žanro pavadinimas</th>
  </tr>
 </thead> 
 <tbody>
     <tr>
      <select name="Zanras">
       <option value="demo1">demo1</option>
                <option value="demo2">demo2</option>
                <option value="demo3">demo3</option>
      </select>
  </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: please attach output screeshot..

Comment: I don't see a `<td>` tag inside `<tr>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing `<td>`s in your `<tbody>`:

```
<tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>
            <select name="Zanras">
            <?php while($row = $resultc->fetch_assoc()) {  
              echo "<option value=" . $row['Zanro_pavadinimas'] . ">" . $row['Zanro_pavadinimas'] . "</option>";
            }
            ?>
            </select>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<table id="myTable" class="table table-inverse table-hover">
    <thead id = "headings" class = "thead-default">
        <tr>
      <th>Žanro pavadinimas</th>
  </tr>
 </thead> 
 <tbody>
     <tr>
      <td>
      <select name="Zanras">
       <option value="demo1">demo1</option>
                <option value="demo2">demo2</option>
                <option value="demo3">demo3</option>
      </select>
  </td>
  </tr>
 </tbody>
```

Answer (score 0):

The `<td>`s are mandatory in `<tr>`.
Also, you should indent your code correctly for better readibility.

```html
<table id="myTable" class="table table-inverse table-hover">
  <thead id="headings" class="thead-default">
    <tr>
      <th>Žanro pavadinimas</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td><select name="Zanras">
        <option value="demo1">demo1</option>
        <option value="demo2">demo2</option>
        <option value="demo3">demo3</option>
      </select></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```